# Nested exception while loading key store in java spring application

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, keystore

I followed this tutorial to create SSL for my spring boot app. [SSL tutorial](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/)

This is my application.properties file

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
```

When I run the application I get this error

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
> start web server; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load
> key store 'classpath:keystore.p12'

I know that there has been already a similar question however it didn't help me. I suppose I should change *server.ssl.key-store* but I have no idea what I should write instead of *classpath:keystore.p12*. I'm not even sure where this file is stored so I could give a correct path nor how to find it's location

Comment: First, you have a keystore, right? You wrote, "I'm not even sure where this file is stored..." but since you created it you should know where it is. If you have a keystore, the tutorial you referenced says, "The first thing to do is placing the keystore file inside the Spring Boot project. We want to put it in the resources folder or the root folder."  Did you try both of those places?  Finally try changing the file location to an absolute file path instead of `classpath:` just to see if you can load it correctly.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for help. I realized I skipped this step and didn't put keysore inside my spring boot project. I found keystore.p12 and keystore.jks in my C:\Windows\System32 however I cant move them to my project. I get "cannot move file" error in IntelliJ. Am I trying to move the wrong files or is there other reason why I can't move them?

Comment: I just moved using Explorer not IntelliJ and it seems to be working